# Redirectiing users to a new domain

Tags: javascript, http, redirect

I want the users visiting `www.xyz.com/whatever/example.html` to be redirected to `www.newdomain.com/whatever/example.html` . While doing that I want to go to an intermediate page to display some information saying that the site has moved to a new domain and automatically redirect after 5-10 seconds .

i.e I just want to change my host name , whatever comes after that in the URL should remain the same  for eg : `www.xyz.com?foo=bar&a=b&c=d` should redirect to `www.newdomain.com?foo=bar&a=b&c=d`

What is the best way to do this ?

My thought was to redirect any incoming page to `www.xyz.com/index.html` and write a javascript function to parse the URL and replace just its host name to www.newdomain.com .  I am able to redirect to `www.xyz.com/index.html` successfully but I lose the original URL information . How can I keep track of that` original URL string ?

Comment: There're so many technologies for redirecting users. Javascript is not the most suitable one.

Comment: Can you suggest some ways based on my requirement ?

Comment: e.g. http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/simple-rewriterule-set-redirect-domain-6570/#.UL8CTXDuKv4

Answer (score 1):

This would be best done on the server, but if it must be accomplished via javascript:

```
var newDomain = "www.xyz.com"
window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + newDomain + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
```

Comment: You forgot `location.query`. From question: "for eg : www.xyz.com?foo=bar&a=b&c=d should redirect to www.newdomain.com?foo=bar&a=b&c=d"

Comment: @trebuchet If I have to do like this , I have to do this in every page right ?

Comment: @premprakash yes, but just put it in a file and include it in your master/header file (or just include the file on every page)

Comment: @trebuchet : There are a lot of pages , I can go and add this information to each page and some are images like www.xyz.com/abc/123.jpg . So this will not work .

Comment: @premprakash your question referred to pages - that would need to be done on the server

Comment: @trebuchet : Not just pages ... files in general. How to do that in the server ? I want to redirect to an intermediate page before redirecting to the exact location in the new domain